# Go-Ethereum: What is the story behind the "bad hashes" in core/blocks.go

Tags: go-ethereum

Go-Ethereum tracks a few "bad hashes". What is the story behind them? Why are they bad? I understand they are "usually hard forks" but it would be interesting to hear more about them, and why they are problematic. What's their story?

```
// BadHashes represent a set of manually tracked bad hashes (usually hard forks)
var BadHashes = map[common.Hash]bool{
    common.HexToHash("05bef30ef572270f654746da22639a7a0c97dd97a7050b9e252391996aaeb689"): true,
    common.HexToHash("7d05d08cbc596a2e5e4f13b80a743e53e09221b5323c3a61946b20873e58583f"): true,
}
```

The modern Geth has two "bad hashes" and the Frontier release codebase had four:

```
// Set of manually tracked bad hashes (usually hard forks)
var BadHashes = map[common.Hash]bool{
    common.HexToHash("f269c503aed286caaa0d114d6a5320e70abbc2febe37953207e76a2873f2ba79"): true,
    common.HexToHash("38f5bbbffd74804820ffa4bab0cd540e9de229725afb98c1a7e57936f4a714bc"): true,
    common.HexToHash("7064455b364775a16afbdecd75370e912c6e2879f202eda85b9beae547fff3ac"): true,
    common.HexToHash("5b7c80070a6eff35f3eb3181edb023465c776d40af2885571e1bc4689f3a44d8"): true,
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the hashes correspond to a consensus issue introduced by the geth client https://blog.ethereum.org/2015/08/20/security-alert-consensus-issue.